# How to load data from PHP to Handsontable with jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, handsontable

I am using [Handsontable](http://handsontable.com/) to display data but I can't load the data that was returned from PHP.

Here is my jQuery code:

```
$("#handsontable").on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
      var container = document.getElementById('existdata');
      var hot = new Handsontable(container, {
          minSpareRows: 1,
          height: '380',
          rowHeaders: true,
          colHeaders: ['col1','col2','col3','col4','col5'],
          contextMenu: false,
          manualColumnResize: true,
          colWidths:[100,100,100,50,450]
      });
});
$(document).on('click','#btn',function(){
    var as = $('input[name="assign"]:checked').val();
    var data = $('#sample').attr('data-file');
    $.post('script/sample.php',{action:'sample',data:data,as:as},function(chk){
            $("#handsontable").modal("show");
            var d = ["","","","",JSON.parse(chk)];
            console.log(JSON.stringify(d))
            $('#existdata').handsontable('loadData', d);
    });
});
```

Here is the data that PHP returned:

```
["","","","",["TOR-038-7459_XCODE_Conforming_SCC_Proxy.wmv"]]
```

I use `console.log(JSON.stringify(d))` to know what my `d` looks like.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out the root of my problem. The problem is the data that AJAX received from my PHP code. The proper data should be `[["","","","","TOR-038-7459_XCODE_Conforming_SCC_Proxy.wmv"]]` and not `["","","","",["TOR-038-7459_XCODE_Conforming_SCC_Proxy.wmv"]]`.